# Peugeot 206 Squeaky Horn

Tags: peugeot, horn, peugeot-206

I'm fairly new to cars and have only been driving for a few months. I had to use my horn recently and realised it sounded like a dying goose. It is making a noise, but it's fairly quiet and sounds like it is squeaking. Almost like it is rubbing against something?

I checked the fuse and it's fine.

I also can't seem to work out where the horn is located so that I could take it out and investigate it for damage/replace it myself.

Any advice on what I could do other than taking it to a garage?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Peugeot?

Comment: It's a 2010 model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They get like this when they've corroded inside and dropped to bits or become stiff. Not a lot to a horn; an electromagnet coupled with a diaphragm, such that power makes the diaphragm move, which disconnects the magnet, which makes the diaphragm spring back, which connects the power, which moves it away again.. the back and forthing making the noise

Just google or eBay for what a 206 horn looks like - horns typically look round (like a big bicycle bell) or snail shell, with a stick coming out (for mounting) - now you know what you're looking for.. jack the car up, or drive it onto large bricks, or half onto a high kerb.. Use a stick wedged between the driver seat and the steering wheel to activate the horn then crawl under and look for the noise. It's possible it'll be inside the fender or behind some other removable panelling but will probably be easily visible and locatable from the sound. It's a one bolt/one electrical connector swap, easy job

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tC5fejFC48g